# Excel compare two strings and return the number of unmatched characters

Tags: excel

I want to compare two strings, and the return value is the number of unmatched characters.

For example:
A1: abc
B1: acde
The cell B1 is compared to A1 and will return 3.

```
A1: abc
B1: a cde
     * **
```

This application is for multiple choice question with more than one answers.
A1 is the correct answer, and B1 selects 3 wrong answers.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?
Thanks!

--
Sorry for my unclear words. 
Assume the question has 5 choices (abcde), and A1 is the correct answer. 
B1 is the answers selected by someone, and he/she selects 3 wrong answers.

Comment: Why is the number of answers different? There are 4 in B1 but only 3 in A1.

Comment: I assume A1 is the correct answer and B1 is the answers selected? VBA would be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear words. Assume the question has 5 choices (abcde), and A1 is the correct answer (abc). B1 is the answers selected by someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula calculates number of unmatched letters `a-e` in `A1` and `B1` cells (no duplicates in one cell):

```
=SUM(MOD(LEN(A1&B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1&B1,{"a","b","c","d","e"},"")),2))
```

Comment: Isn't the OP wanted to take character position into consideration? What if A1 contains "abc" and B1 "acb"? Shoudn't the answer here be 2, and not 0 as your formula gives?

Comment: @XOR LX Op said it's multiple choice test, so I don't think answer order should matter in this case.

Comment: Ok, but in that case why is the OP asking for an answer of 3 for the sample given? They have "abc" in A1 and "acde" in B1. If order doesn't matter, shouldn't the answer be 2, not 3 (only "d" and "e" do not "match")?

Comment: @ XOR LX also "b" doesn't have a match - as ilustrated in the OP's "code"  part of question.

Comment: Ah, I see. I hadn't understood that part, but now I see what you mean. Thanks. Perhaps some responses from the OP would be useful!